# Feynman rules for gravitons in momentum space

Tags: gravity, feynman-diagrams

I have derived a Lagrangian from expanding the Hilbert Albert action, and I don't know how to compute a 3-Graviton vertex. I also would be thankful if someone gives me the right form of the Lagrangian(up to third order) so that I can compare my result.

Comment: I have seen a citations in the literature to the linked paper as the original one in which the 3-Graviton vertex was calculated, but it is not open access so I can't confirm that the citation is accurate. https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.162.1239

Comment: [Veltman 1975](https://blogs.umass.edu/grqft/files/2015/01/Veltman-Quantum_theory_of_gravitation.pdf).

Comment: @CosmasZachos It is disappointing that the world average measurement given for the cosmological constant is only 4% different, and roughly the same order of magnitude of precision today that it was in 1975 (as I noticed skimming the link).

Comment: @ohwilleke. Is it progress if a cannibal uses a fork?  I suspect progress will come from "the inside"...